# Error while updating date time automatically on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to update Ubuntu's date and time automatically, but I get an error for all time servers:

1. asia.pool.ntp.org
2. north-america.pool.ntp.org
3. europe.pool.ntp.org
4. Public Time Server (pool.ntp.org)
5. oceania.pool.ntp.org

How to resolve this problem?

[image: time out]]

Answer (score 0):

For me most ntp.org servers also timed out, but you can find the list of all servers on:
http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/NTPPoolServers

Here you can also see servers based on [zone](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/oceania) and even [country](http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/au). You can also see how many servers are active.

You can add the servers listed on that page to your configuration file:

```
/etc/ntp.conf
```

See more information in the [Ubuntu ntp documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html).

Comment: i get `The connection was reset` error for servers.i tested that on browser

Comment: When exactly do you get this error, and from which program?

Answer (score 0):

You can check time servers manually with `ntpdate -q europe.pool.ntp.org`.

Also, your provider might have a time server you can use, which should be more reliable than a random pool member. It won't hurt to ask them.